# Last failure section in jenkins showing N/A

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-job-dsl

I have configured job in pipeline. for successful execution it shows build number and time taken. but in failure case displays N/A in Last failure column. i am not sure what wrong there.

Answer (score 0):

did you use BUILD_NUMBER global variable ?

in jenkins if you use:

```
 echo env.BUILD_NUMBER
```

you can see your build number

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by changing log rotation in jenkins.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).